# Ajax request will scroll to the top after success.

Tags: jquery, ajax, highcharts

get_queue_data() gets called every 10 secs, which calls the ajax query every 10 sec. The issue is that each time after ajax call gets called, the page scrolls the top. Most of the solutions online tell me to use preventEventDefault. I tried passing a variable to function get_queue_data, and tried calling preventEventDefault. Still doesn't work. I also tried returning false to the get_queue_data function.

```
  get_queue_data();
  setInterval(get_queue_data,10000);

  function get_queue_data() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/a/order/order_process/all_queues_data',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: true,
      success: function (data) {
        for(var k=0;k<22;k++) {
          chart.series[k].addPoint([data.all_queues_data[k]['messages']]);
          var temp_series = chart.series[k];
          average_chart_data[k] = (temp_series.data[temp_series.data.length-1].y+(average_chart_data[k]*(temp_series.data.length-1)))/(temp_series.data.length);
        }

        //console.log(average_chart_data, last_value_chart_data);
        $('#queue_report').highcharts({
          chart: {
            height : 500,
            margin :50,
            width: $('#queue_data').width(),
            events: {
              load: function () {
                function create_label(message, x, y, fill_color, link) {
                  ren.label(message, x, y)
                      .attr({
                        fill: fill_color,
                        stroke: 'white',
                        'stroke-width': 2,
                        padding: 5,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        r: 5
                      })
                      .on('click', function () {
                        var win = window.open(link, '_blank');
                        win.focus();
                      })
                      .add(data.all_queues_data[0][0])
                      .shadow(true);
                }
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Is there anything else on the page that would keep the height of the document? The redraw of the chart replaces the DOM element causing it's height to be 0 for a moment.

Comment: If I were you I would change the container's height to the height of the chart, that should at least keep the page the same height even though you are redrawing the chart.

Comment: @Chris I do have a table to display below the high chart, so setting the height of page to height of chart wont work

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll Yes, the redraw might be the issue. i tried putting the high cart in a div and setting its height to height of the high chart. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, the issue with my code was that, the height of the chart becomes zero, taking me to the start of the page after each ajax call. So, what I did was I created a container with a standard height, inside which I have my high chart. This would make sure the height of the div in which the high chart is never zero. Solved!!

Comment: After I answered in a comment you could've just asked me to put it in an answer (which I did a day later) instead of answering yourself and marking it as answered...

Comment: And here I was thinking people just cared about the answers

Comment: You might want to read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments

Answer (score 1):

The redraw of the chart replaces the DOM element causing it's height to be 0 for a moment.